# Infinite loop in my code

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I have this code but i dnt know why it's running in infinite loop.. I tried to know in debug mode but then even on break it is not returning the control and going on....

```
private static void helper(List<Long> result,List<Long> values,
        Long duration, long tmp, int currPosition) {
    while(currPosition<values.size()){
        if( tmp==duration){
            for (Long long1 : result) {
                values.remove(values.indexOf(long1));
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
            if(values.get(currPosition)<=duration && values.get(currPosition)+tmp<=duration){
                result.add(values.get(currPosition));
                tmp+=values.get(currPosition);
                currPosition++;
                helper(result,values,duration,tmp,currPosition);
            }else if(values.get(currPosition)<=duration && values.get(currPosition)+tmp>duration){
                currPosition++;
                helper(result, values, duration, tmp, currPosition);
            }else if(values.get(currPosition)>duration){
                values.remove(currPosition);
                helper(result, values, duration, tmp, currPosition);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your loop will only exit if `duration` and `tmp` are equal, but they are never updated.

Your loop will run forever unless the arguments are equal (in which case it will run once until the `break;` statement).

Comment: but updated  temp is being passed on as parameter in the recursive method... even in debug mode i can see control going to break but still control is not returning

Comment: @shrutirawat, but you will never break out of the original loop, only the new loops you have recursed into.

Comment: got your point... but i am unable to get a way out. I am updating temp still not able to get out of this recursive loop

Comment: @shrutirawat Without knowing what the loop is doing functionally, I would simply update one of the variables with a return value from the recursed method. i.e. `tmp = helper(result, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

The loop `while(currPosition<values.size())` only stop if you enter:

```
            if( tmp==duration){
            for (Long long1 : result) {
                values.remove(values.indexOf(long1));
            }
            break;
```

And I can't see where you update `tmp` and `duration`, neither where `currPosition` increment the value.
Because `currPosition` is an `int` value, and never is passed to a method as a reference. So `currPosition` has always the same value, never update.

You should have another count to stop the while when the number of iterations were >= the size of the list to stop the main loop.

Comment: if i look at debug mode then control is going to break; and even it is breaking out of current loop but i think the previous loops are continuing to run

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursion without conditional stops. 
Instead of your initial while, you should add:

```
if(currPosition<values.size())
{
  return;
}
```

And you can add more conditions you see appropriate to stop your recursion.

Also, where do you update `duration` and `tmp` ? They should be equal if you want to stop but you're not updating them.

Comment: I am passing updated temp as helper(result,values,duration,tmp+values.get(currPosition),currPosition+1);

Comment: Your logic is simply wrong then. You're not entering the only place that can stop the recursion. the while seems wrong like I wrote and you probably got a mistake in your formula or either some wrong initial values that are not within your assumptions of the input.